# Word 2013 - Create index in other than alphabetical order?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a large document (70 pages) with lots of index entries (XE fields). The index entries refer to books of the Bible (Gen., Exo., Lev., etc.). I need for my index to be in biblical canonical order instead of alphabetical order. Is there any way to do this? Even a macro would be fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Indexes are alphabetical lookups, that's kind of the point. :) Why not use a Table of Contents to list the contents in the order they appear it the document?  Also, please edit your question to include what you've already attempted...

Comment: I am using a TOC, but for the document's headings. They are in document order. For the index, though, I want it in canonical order so that people familiar with the Bible will look for Genesis at the index's beginning and Revelation at the index's end (etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You could use semicolons to override the sort order. What follows the semicolon is where Word would place the entry as if it were in that position.

For example, you could have these index fields:

```
{XE "Creation;01Genesis"}  
{XE "Flood;01Genesis"}  
{XE "Moses;02Exodus"}  
{XE "Serpent;01Genesis"}  
{XE "Babel;01Genesis"}
```

The index would put them in the order of Babel, Creation, Flood, Serpent, and Moses.